# Como mostrar num campo em block uma palavra segundo determinados parâmetros?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Preciso de fazer o display dum nome num campo de uma form com botões.
Se o utilizador selecionar o numero 1 no campo anterior, no campo seguinte em modo block (para que não seja modificável pelo utilizador), deverá mostrar por exemplo a palavra "carreira"; se selecionar o numero 2 deverá mostrar por exemplo "contratro"...; 
Quando o utilizador clica no botão Submeter deverá guardar essa informação (o numero "1", a palavra "carreira" e as outras na base de dados criada previamente criada em phpmyadmin).

[Deixo aqui o código feito até então](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vog8a2250erjye/codigo.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Seja mais claro e coloque exemplos de código do que você já fez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer validar usando o block, veja se serve usando o jQuery mesmo. É bem simples e bem fácil de entender, porém se precisar de algum retorno do PHP avisa, pois seria só adequar ou verificar se o modelo do Antonio serve.

**jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formulario" method="" action="">
 <select id="opcao">
  <option value="">Selecione a opção</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" id="retorno" disabled />
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#opcao').change(function(){
  var selecionado = $(this).val();
  if(selecionado == ""){
   $("#retorno").val("Opção não Selecionada");
  }else{
   if(selecionado == 1){
    $("#retorno").val("Contratro");
   }
   if(selecionado == 2){
    $("#retorno").val("Carreira");
   }
   if(selecionado == 3){
    $("#retorno").val("Outra Opção");
   }
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Exato, a ideia seria algo assim mas não tenho muita prática com jQuery. Coloquei a parte do código do Script num ficheiro JS e fiz o import mas não funcionou: 

<script src="opcoes.js">
</script>

apareceu a janela com "opção 1","opção 2" mas no campo bloqueado não apareceu a palavra Contrato/Carreira depois de selecionada. Também tentei fazendo diretamente onde tenho todo o código:
<script>
      *código do script*
</script>

Comment: Voce indicou onde esta o arquivo jQuery ? exemplo: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script> ou conforme CDN <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: da ultima vez que deu erro por faltar o <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> depois de pôr ficou a funcionar. hoje testei o mesmo código como está e não funciona. o que poderá ser ?

Comment: Abra no Chrome e verifique no console de erros, lá deve aparecer algo, qualquer coisa corre aqui.